# enter credentials after the page is redirected to another page

Tags: javascript, redirect, authentication

I am new to JavaScript and web based programming languages. What I want to do is when someone opens a particular page the user must be redirected to another page and login details should be filled by the script . I don't know how to do that I have tried this:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/access/login/");
window.onLoad(function(){document.getElementById('username').value="xxxx"});
```

The problem it only redirects, but does not enter the details

Comment: why do you need to populate username?

Comment: I need to share my username and password with some others

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply events to another page.

For example, you can pass this username through GET parameter:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/access/login/?username=" + "xxxx");
```

Then, in a `access/login/` page you can insert this `username` using server-side language. For example, using PHP:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>"/>
```

JavaScript can work with GET parameters as well, but it is much better idea to do this at server-side. If you don't have any server language, you can do this using JS:

```
var query = window.location.search.substr(1).split('=');

if (query.length === 0) return; // no username argument

if (query.length === 2 && query[0] === 'username') { 
  document.getElementById('username').value = query[1];
}
```

My solution is definitely not the best one, it is provided just for example. You can do this in your, more elegant and convenient way.

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement a automated login kinda thing and I don't own the redirected page so i cant insert scripts in it

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to fill the text box. Just get the credentials from URL GET and pass it to login function.
No doubt your login page must have a login function.

```
//First check if you have got credentials in URL
if(is_set($_GET['username']))
{
 Your_Login_Function($_GET['username']), $_GET['password']))
}

//Your Page Code Here

Your_Login_Function(username, password)
{
 //function process goes here
}
```

Comment: The problem is I dont own the redirected page
Its something like Iam logging the user with my user id and password to some site like(gmail) which i dont own